# Yo angular generator throwing error

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

Having trouble getting yo angular generator to run, have had no problem on other computers, this is a fresh install on this one. Here is the error

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:89
                throw err0;
                      ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/Alex/.config/configstore'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:751:18)
at Function.sync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:70:13)
at Object.create.all.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/index.js:41:13)
at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:44)
at new Insight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:36:34)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:122:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
```

The odd thing about this is when I go to my users/alex/.config there is no configstore folder.

Answer (score 2):

Probably it´s because you have the .config folder and subsequent ones with root ownership. Try changing the ownership of that folder to your user recursively (to include subfolders). In order to do that:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):staff /Users/Alex/.config/
```

After that, yeoman should run and you'll be able to see the folder.

Hope that helps.